# Wifi issues in Lenovo G460

Tags: wireless

I read several forums and questions, and it seems that everyone have issues with wifi connections, since the last update of 13.04. I've got the same problem with the last kernel update in Fedora18, and for that I had to unistall it (sigh) and try Ubuntu, but it was the same. I tried almost every kind of solution, nothing worked for me.

Does anybody knows when the ubuntu team will solve this problem?

edit: wifi works fine in W7 and my galaxy tab2

Update: Info required

```
sudo lshw -class network

*-network               
   descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
   producto: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   fabricante: Atheros Communications Inc.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:05:00.0
   nombre lógico: wlan0
   versión: 01
   serie: 1c:65:9d:d6:e4:9f
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuración: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   recursos: irq:17 memoria:d6400000-d640ffff
*-network
   descripción: Ethernet interface
   producto: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:06:00.0
   nombre lógico: eth0
   versión: 02
   serie: 1c:75:08:56:2e:76
   tamaño: 100Mbit/s
   capacidad: 100Mbit/s
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   recursos: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memoria:d2410000-d2410fff memoria:d2400000-d240ffff memoria:d2420000-d243ffff


lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated     Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI   Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
05:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

**Now I have this wifi problem on W7, sigh :(. Never happened in w7 before linux messed up my wifi hw**

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you try running the command `nmcli nm wifi on` in the Terminal window that could help.